# Can anyone provide a Roadmap to learn Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: education

I know someone who finished masters in mathematics but literally knows nothing about how to use computers, now he wants to learn how to apply all of the math he knows using computers so I'm doing the research for him. My research results tell me that he should use either Wolfram Mathematica or Matlab or python. Maybe Matlab and python together too. The thing is I want to find him a comprehensive course that teaches him how to use the program and apply the math he knows not to teach him the math because he already knows it. He's French based but knows some English so it's better if it's in French but no problem as long as French subtitles are available or if it's a book even if it's English it can be translated.. As for Matlab I found a couple of courses offered by a university with French subtitles and as for Mathmetica I found some books which can be translated. As for python I found a couple of Udemy courses.

Naming them, The Mathematica books are: 1.Stephen Wolfram - An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language (2017, Wolfram Media)

2.Cliff Hastings, Kelvin Mischo, Michael Morrison - Hands-On Start to Wolfram Mathematica_ And Programming with the Wolfram Language (2016, Wolfram Media)

3.Schaum’s Outline of Mathematica, 3rd Edition (2019, McGraw-Hill Education)

(All can be bought on Amazon)

In Matlab, the courses I found are: Introduction to programming with Matlab offered by Vanderbilt University And the other two courses they offered. (found on coursera for free, but you can pay if u wnat a certificate)

In python I found the courses offered by Mike x Cohen on Udemy.

Of course there are myriad other resources to learn these technologies.

I am here to ask about a Roadmap for Wolfram Mathematica because that's personally what I prefer and I can't find much resources to learn it. Can anyone please provide a well structured Roadmap to learn Wolfram Mathmetica. video courses would be better than books. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Comment: `My research results tell me that he should use either Wolfram Mathematica or Matlab or python.` This really depends on what your friends wants to use the software for,  You just said `how to apply all of the math he knows using computers`  it all depends on what kind of `math` we are talking about.  For analytical/symbolic type math, you should really forget about matlab and python, they are no competition and will be waste of time learning them for someone who wants to do analytical type math computation.  So it all depends of what the math is.. May be ask your Friend about this first.

Comment: @Nasser pure math..

Comment: `pure math` if he is doing pure math, why would you recommend he learns Matlab and Python?  A much better choice will be learning a CAS system.

Answer (score 1):

Read sections [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html) that are related to what they will work on.